Translations for LWC label and description
I have created a LWC component, where I have defined a property called limit like below
<property name="limit" type="Integer" required="true" label="Number of Records to Display" description="Number of Records to Display in the Data Table"/>

User would like to have French translations for label and description. Can anyone help me how can I achieve this?

I did try this one, but it's not working:

Here you have an example of how to use Labels in lwc, being able to perform the translation. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-labels.html

I raised a case with Salesforce, and after investigation they mentioned that the use of custom labels in the js-meta file is presently not supported.
